# A question about a generalization of covariance

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, probability-theory, hilbert-spaces, covariance

Suppose, $H$ is a Hilbert space over $\mathbb{R}$. Suppose, $X$ and $Y$ are random vectors in $H$. Let’s define Hilbert expectation of a random vector $X$ in a Hilbert space $H$ as a vector $v \in H$, such that $\forall u \in H \text{ } (E\langle X, u \rangle = \langle v, u \rangle)$. If a Hilbert expectation exists, then it is unique, due to the fact that every Hilbert space admits an orthonormal basis. Let’s denote Hilbert expectation of a random vector $X$ as $E_HX$. Now let’s define scalar covariance of two random vectors $X$ and $Y$ as $Cov_H(X, Y) = E\langle X, Y\rangle - \langle E_HX, E_HY \rangle$

Is it always true, that if $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then $Cov_H(X, Y) = 0$?

If $H$ is $l_2$ or any its subspace, and $X = (X_n)_{n = 1}^\infty$ and $Y = (Y_n)_{n = 1}^\infty$. Then $Cov_H(X, Y) = \Sigma_{n = 1}^{\infty} EX_nY_n - \Sigma_{n = 1}^{\infty} EX_nEY_n = \Sigma_{n = 1}^{\infty} Cov(X_n, Y_n)$. Thus, if $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then $Cov_H(X, Y) = 0$. And because every separable Hilbert space is isometrically isomorphic to a subspace of $l_2$, the statement is proven for any separable Hilbert space.

However, I do not know, what to do in case, when $H$ is not separable.

Comment: Probably yes, but your "covariance" is so at odds with the usual use of the term in even the Hilbert space $\mathbb R^2$ that I have a hard time getting my head around what you are asking.

Comment: @kimchilover, I changed the name of that thing from "Hilbert covariance" to "scalar covariance" to avoid confusion with covariance operator. Is it all right now?

Comment: Your "Hilbert expectation" is usually called the weak, or Pettis, expectation.  I don't know much about such things, and how to answer your questions.  Have you read the Hilbert space chapter in Parasarathy's _Probability measures on metric spaces_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure the following argument works (I'm just learning this stuff)... critiques & corrections most welcome!

First, we have the usual:

$$
\begin{array}{}
E\langle X-E_H X, Y - E_H Y\rangle &= E\langle X,Y\rangle - E\langle E_H X, Y\rangle - E\langle X, E_H Y\rangle + \langle E_H X, E_H Y\rangle \\
& = E\langle X,Y\rangle - \langle E_H X, E_H Y\rangle = Cov_H(X,Y)
\end{array}
$$

where the first equality is due to linearity, and the second equality is due to e.g. $E\langle X, E_H Y\rangle = \langle E_H X, E_H Y \rangle$ by definition of $E_H X$.

Now if $X,Y$ are independent, $E[\cdot]$ can be written as $E_X [ E_Y[\cdot]]$, in the sense that integrating over the joint distribution is equal to integrating over (the marginal, i.e. unconditioned) $Y$ first and then over (the marginal, i.e. unconditioned) $X$.  So:

$$Cov_H(X,Y) = E_X [ E_Y \langle X-E_H X, Y - E_H Y\rangle ]$$

Now, the inner expression $f(X) = E_Y \langle X-E_H X, Y - E_H Y\rangle$ is a scalar function of $X$.  However, by definition of $E_H Y$ we have:

$$\forall u \in H: E_Y \langle u, Y - E_H Y\rangle = E_Y \langle u, Y\rangle - \langle u, E_H Y\rangle = 0$$

So by substituting $u = X-E_H X$ we have $f(X) \equiv 0$ and $Cov_H(X,Y) = E_X [0] = 0$.

*Sanity check:* if $X,Y$ were dependent (contrary to OP), then $E[\cdot] = E_X[E_{Y|X}[\cdot]]$ and the inner expression, considered as a scalar  function of $X$, becomes $g(X) = E_{Y|X}\langle X-E_H X, Y - E_H Y\rangle$ where the distribution of relevance is the conditional distribution of $Y$ conditioned on the specific input $X$.  We can no longer claim $g(X) \equiv 0$ because nothing allows us to conclude that $E_{Y|X}\langle u, Y\rangle = \langle u, E_H Y\rangle$ for a particular input $X$.